# Gzip reader only reading 32768 bytes at max

Tags: go, buffer, gzip

I am trying to compress fixed slice of struct, while trying to un-zip the same buffer `gzip.Reader` is only reading till `32768` (2^15) at max, causing malformed extracted data.

Below is the code -

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/klauspost/compress/gzip"
)

type Candle struct {
    Open   uint64
    High   uint64
    Low    uint64
    Close  uint64
    Volume uint64
    Time   uint64
    Value1 uint64
    Value2 uint64
    Symbol uint64
}

func main() {
    var data [400]Candle
    buffer := bytes.NewBuffer(make([]byte, 0, 420343))
    writer := gzip.NewWriter(buffer)
    marshalledData, err := json.Marshal(data)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    writer.Write(marshalledData)
    writer.Flush()
    fmt.Println("compressed size", len(buffer.Bytes()), len(marshalledData))

    // uncompress

    fmt.Println("while un-compres size", len(buffer.Bytes()))
    reader, _ := gzip.NewReader(buffer)
    tempData := make([]byte, 640343)
    n, err := reader.Read(tempData)
    fmt.Println("bytes read", n, err)
    var c2 [375]Candle
    tempData = tempData[:n]
    fmt.Println(string(bytes.TrimSpace(tempData)))
    err = json.Unmarshal(bytes.TrimSpace(tempData), &c2)
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

Goplay working link - https://goplay.tools/snippet/QGZqLVi3JvQ

I have tried with both `github.com/klauspost/compress/gzip` and golang default `compress/gzip` libraries still same result.

Although same long, slice of struct is getting compressed and uncompressed with other formats like - lz4

Is there some limitation of gzip or am I missing something ?

Comment: Readers are not required to fill the entire slice in a single call: [Read reads *up to* len(p) bytes into p."](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Reader) To read everything use io.ReadAll or io.Copy.